# Detect if Main UI is closing

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently developing a class library. I'm having trouble finding a way to detect if the Main UI is closing.

Is there a way to know that from the class library project?

My purpose of this is to cancel all the threads that is currently running if the Main UI is closing.

Comment: What do u mean by main ui in a class library? some code can help us

Comment: Main UI is the User of the DLL that im currently Developing

Comment: So you have to track events of Main UI. Because user is able to interact with it.

Comment: @simsim Please don't use code markdown for things that aren't code...

Comment: @HassanNisar The fact that Main UI knows about the DLL doesn't mean (even even shouldn't) that the DLL knows about the Main UI.

Comment: My Question got -2 anything wrong with my question above?

Comment: @bRaNdOn It doesn't demonstrate research effort, it's vague and doesn't show your own attempts to solve issue.

Comment: I've detailed all the information of my problem.

Comment: @bRaNdOn No, you didn't. For example, you don't describe what type of coupling is there between the DLL and Main. And still - you should present results of your own research and your own attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your DLL, reference the *Syste.Windows.Forms* class library
Then, in your DLL constructor, add the event for Application Exit as follows:

```
public class MyDLLClass
{
    public MyDLLClass()
    {
        Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);
    }

    void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Your thread handling code...
    }
}
```

And that's it!

**Test in my windows form:**

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyDLL_NameSpace.MyDLLClass ff = new MyDLL_NameSpace.MyDLLClass();
    }
```

**Debugging (closing the application):**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use [ApplicationExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit(v=vs.110).aspx) event in `Program.cs` file, provided you have list of all the running threads, you could close.

```
Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);


static void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Other option is to track `FormClosing` event for the main Form.

Comment: Im in a class library i dont have access in main form. So i dont have Program.cs

Comment: Ok somehow I skipped class library in your question. But still you have to handle it in the Main UI project.

Answer (score 1):

The main form has events like OnClose which you can handle. Just subscribe to the proper event and there You go. You can, even use overrides in some cases which allow you to do individual actions before or instead of the defaults. Therefore often OnDispose is overridden.

Answer (score 1):

The FormClosing event can be handled inside your class library by passing the Form into its constructor. You can register a private event handler inside your thread management class, and when this is called cancel your threads within the event handler.

In this example I've used a `CancellationTokenSource` to provide cancellation to any threads running within the class.

```
public class ThreadManager()
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public ThreadManager(Form form)
    {
        form.FormClosing += OnFormClosing;
    }

    private void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

If you construct the thread manager within your form, you can register it like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private ThreadManager threadMgr;

    public MainForm()
    {
        threadMgr = new ThreadManager(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi im on a Class library so FormClosing Event is not going to fire if the MAIN UI closes

Comment: What do you mean by Main UI then?

Comment: Im creating a DLL which will be reference by the MainUI basically The user of DLL

Comment: Okay, I'm going to assume that you have a Form. I've expanded my answer above to include detail on registering the example class within a form.

Answer (score 1):

You can make all your threads [background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Background threads won't keep the main application running and will be automatically closed when application exits:

> Background threads are identical to foreground threads with one exception: a background thread does not keep the managed execution environment running. Once all foreground threads have been stopped in a managed process (where the .exe file is a managed assembly), the system stops all background threads and shuts down.

You can change it for your threads setting the [`Thread.IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

As [magos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548997/magos) correctly points out in comments below a drawback of this solution is that your threads won't have any chance to do some cleanup. Memory and handles shouldn't be a problem, because OS will release them, but things like uncommited transactions can cause issues in the long run.

---

Another, design-level idea is to equip your library with a `Closing` function and let the Main UI call it from `ApplicationExit` or `FormClosing` events. If it's possible, then this looks like the cleanest solution.

Comment: I think readers should be aware that this is not suitable if the threads need to perform cleanup before termination.

Comment: @magos Thanks, fair point. *Most* things will be released by the OS anyway, but not all, so this is indeed an important information.

Answer (score 1):

Your class library shouldn't reach into your UI application at all. There's a reason for it to be a class library in the first place, right?

Give the related classes in the library ShutDown methods and let your UI application listen for its own shutdown events. In the event callbacks you tell the workers etc. of the class library to shut down.